# Can't concatenate pandas dataframes with the same length?

Tags: python, pandas, join, concatenation, right-join

This is weird. From the documentation I all ready read how to do [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes) and merge operations with pandas. Also I all ready know that concatenating to the right side can be done as follows:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

**The issue is that I generated the following dataframes:**

In:

```
links = pd.DataFrame(links, columns=['link'])
```

So, I just want to concatenate the `link` dataframe column to `intersection` dataframe (note that `link` and `intersection` have 78 instances of length). Thus:

In:

```
full_table = pd.concat([lis_, lis_2], axis=1)
```

The problem is that as you can see in the above dataframe, it added some `NaN` values. Therefore, which is the correct way of concatenating `links` and `intersection` dataframes?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your indexes don't match up. Try using the `ignore_index` parameter:

```
full_table = pd.concat([intersection, links], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Your index is clearly the problem. Just compare the output of your link and intersection dataframes above (one index starts at 0 and the other starts at 1). Try resetting the indexes manually with `df.index = list(range(len(df)))` for each.